# How can i modify html element in node js

Tags: html, node.js

So I have a website I need to modify HTML element In a login form like it will show if the username is wrong I need it to check in the server-side then modify it so it will display the text to the client-side

my website is chat app the current code i tried is

```
app.post("/signup", function (req, res) { 
function makerror(message) {
    // idk
}
if (req.body.username) {
    const emailregex = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
    if (!req.body.email.match(emailregex)) {
        return makerror("Please enter a vaild Email");
    }
    const passwordregex = /^.{8,}$/
    if (!req.body.password.match(passwordregex)) {
        return makerror('Your password must be 8 characters long.')
    }
    const usernameregex = /^[a-zA-z0-9]{3,25}$/g
    if (!req.body.username.match(usernameregex)) {
        return makerror('Your username must contain only character from A to Z, Underscores and number from 0 to 9')
    }
    const data = new Userdata({ username: req.body.username, password: scureJs.encrypt(req.body.password), email: req.body.email })
    data.save()
    const obj = {
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
        unix: Math.round(new Date() * 1000)
    }
    const cookie = scureJs.serialize(obj)
    res.cookie('sessionId', cookie, {
        expires: false,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'lax',
    })
    console.log(cookie)
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

})

my app is chat app

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with nodejs then you need to make a form first. Normally we put username and password there.
Then attach sql or database felicities to store the data and on a form submit check those.
Then show your desired input as you go with async load or not.

```
Client(Form Data)---->Server(NodeJS)---->Database Check
      ^                    |
      |                    |
      |                    |
       --------------------
```

Comment: i made a form..

Comment: @sleepy Honestly we need more context, as in how is the request going to be received? is it an API/Web Server? is it a Client-Side-based app? etc otherwise we cant give recommendations unless they are to give suggestions on possible ways to do so. Essentially your question is too vague.

Comment: @MysticSeagull i edited it now

Comment: @sleepy so in this case you need to return errors to the client-side then display the received errors with javascript. and basically, until no errors are returned then it will be successful otherwise keep telling the user there were validation errors.

Comment: yes i need that